# QGIS Export GeoPDF (picture quality)

Tags: qgis, pdf

Exporting the map to GeoPDF. Tell me why the quality of the picture changes? The scale map is the same, the DPI is the same, I change the coverage of the map - the quality of the picture is reduced.
The result (screenshots) was exported to the Global Mapper as raster layer. I don't think that the GM program is perfect and definitely works with GeoPDF. Perhaps I missed something? The result makes me sad

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the type of layers in the view.